# mmap: can't attach to existing region without knowing its size (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, mmap

I'm trying to attach to an existing shared memory region created by another application, not written in Python (this is how its plugin modules intercommunicate).  On Windows, it uses named kernel objects rather than files in the filesystem; Python's mmap module supports this, via the `tagname` parameter.  The problem is that I have no way of knowing in advance what the size of the shared region is - this is a configuration parameter of the other application, which is adjusted based on the expected volume of data.  For file-based shared regions, passing zero for the size uses the existing size of the file, but this apparently doesn't work for tagged regions.  Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying:

```
import mmap, random

TAGNAME = 'SHM_1001'

# This is a simulation of what the other application does.
# The size isn't actually random, I simply don't know in advance what it is.
m1 = mmap.mmap(-1, random.randint(1e3, 1e6), TAGNAME)

# This is what I'm trying to do in my application, to attach to the same region.
m2 = mmap.mmap(-1, 0, TAGNAME)
# WindowsError: [Error 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

If I specify a small nonzero size, then I can successfully attach to the region - but of course I can then only access that many bytes at the start of the region.  If I specify a size larger than the actual size of the region (perhaps equal to the largest size it can ever have), I get an access error.  The problem exists in both Python 2.7 and 3.4.

The approach of passing zero for the size definitely works at the system call level - that is exactly how every existing C/C++ plugin for this application works - so the problem is apparently in Python's wrapper for the mmap() call.  Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter validation in [`CreateFileMapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537) is erroring out before the system service [`NtCreateSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff566428) gets called, which if called would find the existing section. Using 0 size when `hFile` is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` (-1) is invalid because `CreateFileMapping` presumes (wrongly in this case) that the section needs to be allocated from the paging file. I assume C plugins are instead calling [`OpenFileMapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366791) (i.e. [`NtOpenSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567029)).

You can use ctypes, or PyWin32, or a C extension module. After calling `OpenFileMappingW`, call `MapViewOfFile` and then call `VirtualQuery` to get the mapped region size, rounded up to a page boundary.

Here's an example using ctypes.

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

FILE_MAP_COPY       = 0x0001
FILE_MAP_WRITE      = 0x0002
FILE_MAP_READ       = 0x0004
FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS = 0x001f
FILE_MAP_EXECUTE    = 0x0020

PVOID = LPVOID
SIZE_T = c_size_t

class MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _fields_ = (('BaseAddress',       PVOID),
                ('AllocationBase',    PVOID),
                ('AllocationProtect', DWORD),
                ('RegionSize',        SIZE_T),
                ('State',             DWORD),
                ('Protect',           DWORD),
                ('Type',              DWORD))

PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION = POINTER(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)

def errcheck_bool(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise WinError(get_last_error())
    return args

kernel32.VirtualQuery.errcheck = errcheck_bool
kernel32.VirtualQuery.restype = SIZE_T
kernel32.VirtualQuery.argtypes = (
    LPCVOID,                   # _In_opt_ lpAddress
    PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION, # _Out_    lpBuffer
    SIZE_T)                    # _In_     dwLength

kernel32.OpenFileMappingW.errcheck = errcheck_bool
kernel32.OpenFileMappingW.restype = HANDLE
kernel32.OpenFileMappingW.argtypes = (
    DWORD,   # _In_ dwDesiredAccess
    BOOL,    # _In_ bInheritHandle
    LPCWSTR) # _In_ lpName

kernel32.MapViewOfFile.errcheck = errcheck_bool
kernel32.MapViewOfFile.restype = LPVOID
kernel32.MapViewOfFile.argtypes = (
    HANDLE, # _In_ hFileMappingObject
    DWORD,  # _In_ dwDesiredAccess
    DWORD,  # _In_ dwFileOffsetHigh
    DWORD,  # _In_ dwFileOffsetLow
    SIZE_T) # _In_ dwNumberOfBytesToMap

kernel32.CloseHandle.errcheck = errcheck_bool
kernel32.CloseHandle.argtypes = (HANDLE,)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import mmap

    NPAGES = 9
    PAGE_SIZE = 4096

    TAGNAME = 'SHM_1001'
    mm1 = mmap.mmap(-1, PAGE_SIZE * NPAGES, TAGNAME)

    hMap = kernel32.OpenFileMappingW(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, False, TAGNAME)
    pBuf = kernel32.MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0)
    kernel32.CloseHandle(hMap)

    mbi = MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION()
    kernel32.VirtualQuery(pBuf, byref(mbi), PAGE_SIZE)

    assert divmod(mbi.RegionSize, PAGE_SIZE) == (NPAGES, 0)
    mm2 = (c_char * mbi.RegionSize).from_address(pBuf)

    # write using the mmap object
    mm1.seek(100)
    mm1.write(b'Windows')

    # read using the ctypes array
    assert mm2[100:107] == b'Windows'
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this:

> If length is larger than the current size of the file, the file is
>   extended to contain length bytes. If length is 0, the maximum length
>   of the map is the current size of the file, except that if the file is
>   empty Windows raises an exception (you cannot create an empty mapping
>   on Windows).

But currently it seems, that it is a known bug: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/bugs/571941?search_string=1733986;#571941